# Постановка тире перед "это"

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите! Не знаю, можно ли здесь ставить тире перед словом "это"... Изначально было. но мне не нравится. Знаю, что предложение вообще очень сложное, но пока не придумала, как переделать. И запятая тоже лишняя, видимо... После потребителя тоже хочется поставить тире. Можно?
Как и для любого изделия, - это прежде всего выполнение всех назначенных функций в течение всего назначенного жизненного цикла (одноразовый стержень и вечное перо имеют разный жизненный цикл, но с точки зрения ИКР оба эти решения идеальны как с точки зрения производителя, так и с точки зрения потребителя: массового для одноразового стержня и эксклюзивного для вечного пера).

Answer (score 1):

Возможен такой вариант: Как и для любого изделия,  это прежде всего выполнение всех положенных функций в течение всего назначенного жизненного цикла (одноразовый стержень и вечное перо имеют разный жизненный цикл, но, по мнению ИКР, оба эти решения идеальны как с точки зрения производителя, так и с точки зрения потребителя -  массового для одноразового стержня и эксклюзивного для вечного пера).

Тире после сравнительного оборота не нужно, потому что это не тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, а вот в конце предложения оно на месте как обособление однородных определений в финале.

Comment: Большое спасибо! А "прежде всего" запятыми не выделяются? И еще вы специально заменили "с точки зрения ИКР" на "по мнению ИКР"?

Comment: "Прежде всего" здесь несёт смысловую нагрузку КАК?-"в первую очередь", "раньше всего прочего", т.е. является обстоятельством образа действия, на него падает логическое ударение. Но возможно поставить и запятые, как при вводном, если не видите логического ударения. Заменила"с точки зрения ИКР", чтобы убрать повтор.

Comment: ИКР там - идеальный конечный результат, поэтому не подходит.

Comment: МОжет быть так?

Как и для любого изделия, это, прежде всего, выполнение всех назначенных функций в течение всего назначенного жизненного цикла (одноразовый стержень и вечное перо имеют разный жизненный цикл, но с точки зрения ИКР оба эти решения идеальны как для производителя, так и для потребителя – массового для одноразового стержня и эксклюзивного для вечного пера).

Comment: Тогда так: Как и для любого изделия, это прежде всего выполнение всех положенных функций в течение всего назначенного жизненного цикла (одноразовый стержень и вечное перо имеют разный жизненный цикл, но, учитывая ИКР(или имея в виду ИКР), оба эти решения идеальны как с точки зрения производителя, так и с точки зрения потребителя - массового для одноразового стержня и эксклюзивного для вечного пера).

Comment: Да, Ваш второй вариант проще и лучше.